# How do I defeat the Dungeon Guardian?

Tags: terraria

So apparently, as of the last update, there is a special "Baby Skeletron Head" pet one can obtain by killing the [Dungeon Guardian](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon_Guardian).

Last I checked (or died trying), I died from an instantaneous one  hit kill from the Guardian.

How in the world am I supposed to kill the Dungeon Guardian to get his drop for the pet without dying?  This seems completely impossible to me; is there any strategy to kill this guy?

Comment: According to the wiki: "Dungeon Guardian will always take 1 damage from all attacks (except criticals, which deal 2 damage) and will kill any player in one hit".  It suggests [Minishark](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Minishark) with [Crystal Bullets](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Crystal_Bullet) and eays travel abilities.

Comment: How good are you at running away?

Comment: *"there is a special "Bone Guardian" pet one can obtain by killing the Dungeon Guardian"* - source?  I don't see it listed in the [change log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nubZZSGBoUiuKFKzWT7raMrPI35MQtDWSsL-MbHFgqs/preview?sle=true).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I meant http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Baby_Skeletron_Head

Comment: There is a video of a fellow beating the dungeon guardian. It took him about 15 minutes. At the end, it simply disappeared, no drops, no nothing. This was before the latest update and I don't know if it was PC or console. True (unless they doctored the video or something).

Comment: @MrBoJangles I've seen the video also and it was definitely not in this current patch. He uses gravitation potions and a megashark/crystal bullets i believe. Though Ichor Bullets may or may not be better. They reduce target's defense but I'm not sure if it's enough to actually increase your damae against it. Also the Skeletron Head does drop from it. Most likely 100%.

Comment: -_- Just watch Yrimir's video. -_-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<s>[Lawtonfogle's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133676/49683) works if you have two people, but if you want to do it solo, there are two ways:</s> **Note**: Lawtonfogle's answer no longer works as of patch 1.2.0.3.

- Actually fight him. (This is now the only way as of 1.2.0.3.) You should use Gravitation Potions, a Megashark (preferrably Unreal), and Crystal Bullets (so that you can hit multiple times because of the shards that fly out of them). Also have Spectre Boots, so that you move as fast as possible. (Spectre Boots, unlike Hermes boots, still give you the speed boost while flying.) The new Lightning Boots would be preferable; they go even faster.
- <s>Use [Turtle Armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Turtle_armor) and [Black Belt](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Black_Belt), and there is a chance the Black Belt will let you dodge the first hit, while still bouncing back damage. Then on the second hit, you will die, but the Guardian will die too. (Of course, there's a very small chance that you'll survive two hits, leaving you unharmed and one Guardian dead.)</s> **Note**: no longer works in 1.2.0.3. The Guardians now only do 1000 damage, so it takes 10 bounce-backs to kill them.

[source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon_Guardian)

Comment: Just curious.  If you can only deal 1 damage to him anyways, why bother using crystal bullets? Why not just regular?

Comment: @Retrosaur The shards that fly out of them, which can hit him multiple times

Answer (score 4):

You use [turtle armor](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Turtle_Armor) with 2 friends.  Turtle armor does full damage back to the attacker.  Two of you being killed while wearing turtle armor should kill it with the last guy picking up the drop.  Good luck getting the armor.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpS10cO-2Aw) is a video showing how it can be done.  They use a black belt and a lot of luck (and a lot of tries) to dodge the guardian twice in a row while it kills itself due to the turtle armor.

Comment: so there's no way to do it solo?

Comment: @spartacus [There is](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133787/49683)

Comment: As of patch 1.2.0.3 this method no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

> As of 1.2.0.3, the Dungeon Guardian now deals less damage (reduced from 9000 to 1000), to avoid exploits using Turtle armor and a Black Belt or Master Ninja Gear.

From the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bone_Key).

Comment: What wiki?  There's more than one Terraria wiki, so it's important to link to the one you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

This guy is probably the toughest "boss" in the game. With all forms of damage turning into a measly 1 (2 with crits), fat damage, namely melee, won't do much to help you kill one, not to mention that going melee almost ensures your death from the close range. I'm going to assume that you've beaten Moon Lord ,because without post-Moon Lord gear, this fight is extremely hard. Mounts are a requirement for this fight.

**Weapons and Ammo(choose one):**

- **Chain Gun>S.D.M.G>Megashark>Pirhana Gun**
- **Chlorophyte≈Crystal>Endless Musket Pouch**
- **Phantasm>Tsunami**
- **Luminite>Endless Quiver**

**Armor:** Vortex for crits and movement speed; this can be substituted with Shroomite but id not as effective due to the loss of the buff when moving.

**Accessories/Other Items:**

- **Destroyer Emblem**
- **Eye of the Golem**
- **Putrid Scent**
- **Any set of Wings** (preferrable, but not required)
- **Tabi/Master Ninja Gear** (to get to mountable space/asphalt very quickly, not needed if mount is ready)
- **Mounts that fly or are VERY fast (e.x., Cosmic Car Key. Blessed Apple)**

These accessories are mostly for the crits, since mobility is covered by the armor and mount.

**Arena:**
A skybridge should suffice if you have already obtained either the Cosmic Car Key or Blessed Apple, but if you haven't, then a skybridge of asphalt will also work. I haven't tested the asphalt skybridge out, but it certainly seems like a perfectly viable option. You also want to have a quick way out of the dungeon, so mine out the entire area and place a platform right at 0 feet for a quick escape to the skybridge.

**The Fight**

**Kite like a man** and keep him on the very left or right of your screen. The preparations are harder than the fight, and if you use all of the methods I give, you can easily finish it off!

Happy Hunting!